# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop - already assigned key

Tags: reactjs, object, error-handling, key

I am getting this error:

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at Easy
    at div
    at Central
    at div
    at Main
    at App
```

I wrote the following code.

```
import React from 'react'
import Riddlees_comp from './riddlees_comp'


function Easy() {


const riddles_ = [{
   id:1,
   state_:[],
},
   {
   id:2,
   state_: false,
   }]

   return (
       riddles_.map(function(x){
           return <Riddlees_comp key={riddles_.id} riddles_ = {x} />
       })
   )
}

export default Easy
```

I am getting this error even though I already assigned a key to the function. What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**key={x.id}** *instead of*  **key={riddles_.id}**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
<Riddlees_comp key={x.id} riddles_ = {x} />
```

Change **key={riddles_.id}** to **key={x.id}**

Answer (score 0):

You are assigining the same Key to each Riddles_comp

```
<Riddles_comp key={x.id} />
```

Answer (score 0):

To guarantee that the key is unique, it's best to use an index identifier instead, if you don't plan to reuse the `key` variable in the component again. Popular practice is:

```
riddles_.map(function(x,index){
    return <Riddlees_comp key={index} riddles_ = {x} />
})
```